# How to remove responsive support Bootstrap 3.0.0-wip

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to remove all responsive, but I can not yet.

> At a high level, we're dropping IE7 and FF3.6 support, combining standard and responsive CSS into a single file, and consolidating additional code as appropriate.

Anyone know how to do?

Comment: bootstrap is still in development, and even added commits 8 minutes ago.. If you don't need responsive layout, bootstrap 3 (and wip) isn't for you, at the moment, since having it responsive by default is one of the main features..

Answer (score 0):

you don't add the `bootstrap-responsive.css` or `bootstrap-responsive.min.css` for your page.

Comment: There is not a separate `bootstrap-responsive.css' file in BS 3